# USB ports not powered when laptop is asleep?

Tags: laptop, usb, power, charging, asus-laptop

I just bought a brand new [ASUS ROG Strix GL502VY](https://www.asus.com/us/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-GL502VT/) and none of the USB ports charge my phone while the laptop is <s>off</s> asleep, as expected and advertised.  I've googled the issue and can't find anything relevant.  My understanding is that this is the default functionality. I have the `ASUS USB Charger+` app installed (though I'm not sure this is relevant) and have checked the BIOS and didn't see any related settings.

Is there a way to enable this?

Comment: Is the laptop off or in sleep mode. Also, your power saving settings can disable it as well. Usually those don't charge when off, just in standby or sleep mode. Check your power saving options and set them to performance. See if that works. If not you'll have to keep it from fully powering down

Comment: This should be closed, or you can delete it.

Comment: Why do you say that?  I just found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to disable "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" in the Power Management properties of the USB controller.  Now the two USB 3.0 ports (with the high-power indicator) both charge my phone while the laptop is in sleep mode (not "off" as I indicated in the original question)

[image]