# Enable USB 2.0 port charging when laptop is asleep?

Tags: usb, sleep

The Acer TravelMate P2410-G2-M has one USB 3.0 port and three USB 2.0 ports [1,2].  I found out the hard way that if I plug a device into a USB 2.0 port, it stays on but doesn't charge, which depletes its charge.  I assume that it is related to the fact that my laptop is configured to sleep when the lid is closed, which is the way I want it.  Fortunately, the USB 3.0 port charges devices when the laptop is asleep (I later discovered, with some experimentation).  I still wanted to enable charging from the USB 2.0 ports, however, for reasons described in the Annex below.

Many websites explain how to enable USB charging when a laptop is asleep [3,4].  You basically have to disable "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".  The baffling thing, however, is that my USB 3.0 charges when the laptop is asleep but "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is *not* disabled for "USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)".  This suggests that at least for my laptop, I shouldn't have to disable this setting to allow charging when the laptop is asleep.

I note that I have no such "USB Root Hub" for USB 2.0.  I have a "Generic USB Hub" for which "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is not disabled.  Even if I disable it, however, the USB 2.0 port doesn't charge my device when the laptop is asleep, so it is probably not the right "device" to adjust for the USB 2.0 ports.

Following the SuperUser Q&A [5], I also disabled "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" for "Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)".  This also didn't work.

How do I enable charging for the USB 2.0 ports when the laptop is asleep?  And how much difference does it make to conservation of laptop power when there is no device connected?

### Notes

[1] https://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Document/User%20Manual/User%20Manual_Acer_2.0_A_A.pdf?acerid=637086921513006370&Step1=&Step2=&Step3=TRAVELMATE%20P2410-G2-M&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6

[2] https://static.acer.com/up/Resource/Acer/Docs/IN/20191114/TMP2410%20Brochure%20v3.pdf

[3] https://www.thewindowsclub.com/charge-phone-sleep-mode-laptop-lid-closed

[4] https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-charge-your-phone-when-laptop-is-in-sleep-mode

[5] [USB ports not powered when laptop is asleep?](https://superuser.com/questions/1102482)

### Annex: Why enable USB 2.0 charging when laptop is asleep

Even though the USB 3.0 port charges when the laptop is asleep, I still want to enable charging from the USB 2.0 ports for three reasons.

First, I have USB 2.0 ports and just one USB 3.0 port.

Secondly, I want to avoid an episode like today, where I lost a good part of the afternoon thinking that the uncharged device was dead.  It wasn't.  All I needed to do was wait a while before trying to charge it again (using a proper charging port).  Before I found this out, however, I lost the afternoon trying to replace it.  It is an MP3 player, which is no longer sold in brick-and-mortar stores, but I didn't know that when I set out to find a replacement.  Hence, much of the afternoon was lost trying to find one.

Thirdly and finally, I am working from home and juggling multiple laptops on a small desk.  When not in use, some are propped against the wall on their side.  I need the freedom to be able to choose the ports on the same side as the power port, as that is the side that is not on the table.

Comment: I am confused. If an option is “not disabled” doesn’t that mean it’s enabled? The behavior you describe typically wasn’t offered on USB 2.0 ports. Device charging typically was a feature of dedicated USB 3.0 ports or even special USB headers requiring specific device drivers.

Comment: I assume that if you enable "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power", that allows the computer to not charge via the associated USB port[s], i.e., you're enabling the not-charging while the laptop is asleep. My googling indicates that USB 2.0 does charge devices. In my situation, it charges. The problem is how to ensure that it charges when the laptop is turned off.